# Problem with ajax request and directory structure after site migration

Tags: php, ajax, htaccess

If this is the wrong place for this let me know.

I have a wp site I am trying to set up on localhost for dev that uses ajax requests that resolve to root (/).

The problem I have is that the requests are being interpreted as `http://localhost/user/` not `http://localhost/public_html` because of the extra folder in the structure.

Original site:

```
domain > public_html > wpinstall
```

However in my local and shared hosts it is:

```
domain > user > public_html > wpinstall
```

This means roots child is `user` not `public_html` like it needs to be and the site 404's.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: you are doing ajax wrong. fix your code to use proper wordpress ajax api

Comment: I didnt write it i'm taking the site over, hence the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines to the bottom of your `wp-config.php`. Right above the line that says to stop editing.

`define( 'WP_HOME' , 'http://localhost/public_html' );
   define( 'WP_SITEURL' , 'http://localhost/public_html' );`

Comment: @JPB Please accept my answer if it solved your problem. Thanks

Comment: Hi mate. It was late evening  my time when you posted. Just got up will be testing later asap. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Unfortunantely this was not the solution as I already had this in General settings. It appears I need a redirect to append /public_html to /